# How to used "web request by spring mvc" and "rest by jersey" in spring boot

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, jersey, spring-boot

Hi i want to handle web request by spring mvc and handle rest by jersey
in the same project (Spring-Boot)

As i test Rest service is working but web is not
How can i set Application Config ?

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {ProductsResource.class, MessageService.class,Web.class})
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean jerseyServlet() {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(new ServletContainer(), "/rest/*");
        registration.addInitParameter(ServletProperties.JAXRS_APPLICATION_CLASS, JerseyInitialization.class.getName());
        return registration;
    }


    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean webMVC() {
        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet();

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.register(ResourceConfig.class);
        dispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

        ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet, "*.html");
        servletRegistrationBean.setName("web-mvc");
        return servletRegistrationBean;
    }
```

Web Controller

```
@Controller
@Component
public class Web {

    @RequestMapping("/foo")
    String foo() {
        return "foo";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/bar")
    String bar() {
        return "bar";
    }

}
```

Rest Controller

```
@Path("/")
@Component
public class ProductsResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually with spring boot (I'm talking about version 1.4.x), it's pretty easy to do Spring MVC and JAX-RS(rest by jersey) at the same time :). You don't need any servlet registrations. All you need to do is to add a `Configuration` class like the following

```
@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        packages("your.package.with.rest.resources");
    }
}
```

Now all your JAXRS resources are served under `/rest/*`

For example, your Rest Controller can be refactored as

```
@Path("/hello")
@Component
public class ProductsResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Now if you hit url `http://server:port/rest/hello`, **Hello World** should be returned.

Finally, remember to add the following dependencies in your maven pom file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

That should work for you.